# How to fix React Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy

I'm trying to use createProxyMiddleware to serve a static page

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');


const app = express();

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/api', { 
  target: 'http://themis-server.test.seewo.com', 
});


app.use('/api', apiProxy);
app.listen(3000);
```

But I got `Cannot GET /`in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've done something error creating the **createProxyMiddleware** object. Use it as the declaration of the provided official documentation.

```
app.use(
  '/api',
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://themis-server.test.seewo.com',
    changeOrigin: true,
  })
);
```

Comment: hmm i still got the same error